# Keep null records only if there's no other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the table below, how can I write a query where I keep for each category and code, only records with null on "product from" if there's no record with a value on "product from"?

```
> Category | Code | Product From | Product To
> :--------|------|--------------|----------
> Sports   |  A   |     ProdA    |    ProdB
> Sports   |  A   |     NULL     |    ProdB
> Sports   |  A   |     ProdX    |    ProdB
> Sports   |  B   |     NULL     |    ProdB
> Sports   |  C   |     ProdC    |    ProdD
> Sports   |  C   |     NULL     |    ProdD
```

Since for code A, there is two "product from" for the ProdB, the row with NULL as 'Product From' should be removed. For code C, the same happens but for code B, the ProdB should be kept since there's no "Product From" for it.

Expected result:

```
> Category | Code | Product From | Product To
> :--------|------|--------------|----------
> Sports   |  A   |     ProdA    |    ProdB
> Sports   |  A   |     ProdX    |    ProdB
> Sports   |  B   |     NULL     |    ProdB
> Sports   |  C   |     ProdC    |    ProdD
```

Comment: What if there are more than two records for a code?

Comment: then we should keep both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option is to use `WITH TIES`.

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  mytable
 Order by row_number() over (Partition by Category,Code,Product_To Order by Product_From desc)
```

**Returns**

```
Category    Code    Product_From    Product_To
Sports      A       ProdA           ProdB
Sports      B       NULL            ProdB
Sports      C       ProdC           ProdD
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there's two rows with Product_From for the same Product_To then both should be kept

Comment: @GustavoKnx Perhaps you can change row_number() to dense_rank()

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function in a subquery to check if all records are null within groups of records having the same `code`, and apply the logic in the outer query:

```
select category, code, product_from, product_to
from (
    select
        t.*
        max(product_from) over(partition by code) max_product_from
    from mytable t
) x 
where 
    product_from is not null
    or max_product_from is null
```

If all `product_from`s within the partition are `null`, the window `max` returns `null`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38ac9176ab6f54cf701be99a7687ecba)**:

```
category | code | product_from | product_to
:------- | :--- | :----------- | :---------
Sports   | A    | ProdA        | ProdB     
Sports   | B    | null         | ProdB     
Sports   | C    | ProdC        | ProdD
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all, it's not taking the Category in consideration for the partition